# Simple conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I think that
    P(X|Z)=P(X|Y)P(Y|Z)
is true, and doing some calculations in two different ways, it appears to be correct.  However, I'm not sure and can't seem to prove it.  Is it true, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in general false. Toss a fair coin twice. Let $X$ be the event head on first, $Y$ the event head on second, $Z$ the event head on both.

Then $\Pr(X|Z)=1$, but $\Pr(X|Y)\Pr(Y|Z)\ne 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false.  Using the definition of conditional probability, we have

$$P(X | Z) = \dfrac{P(X \cap Z)}{P(Z)}$$

and

$$\begin{aligned}
P(X | Y)P(Y | Z) &= \dfrac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)} \cdot \dfrac{P(Y \cap Z)}{P(Z)}
\end{aligned}$$